serviio with ffmpeg on server 22.04 refuses to display .mpg and .mp4 files
Both packages installed using apt.  Starting serviio using the shell script which has had the SERVIIO_JAVA_OPTS variable 'ffmpeg.location' edited to point at /usr/bin/ffmpeg. All ffmpeg helper drivers as described in the serviio F.A.Q. have been installed.
I haven't found anything to configure ffmpeg.
What have I missed?
